# How to get only new tagged pictures in real time in Instagram

Tags: instagram, real-time-updates

When I use the following api

```
https://api.instagram.com/v1/tags/<tag>/media/recent?access_token=TOKEN&min_tag_id=<min_id>
```

I got all new pictures with "tag" in caption but also all pictures but also old pictures newly commented with this "tag"

I want to get only new pictures tagged with "tag" in caption, not the old ones. Is there a way to do that using the /media/recent API ?

Thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you will have to get the tag photos data using api:

`https://api.instagram.com/v1/tags/<tag>/media/recent?access_token=TOKEN`

and then manually search for the tag in `caption`

Comment: +1 but I would say that checking the created_time might be more convenient than matching text within the caption

Comment: @SteveCrawford ya, true created_time will be more accurate

Comment: Compare created_time with what ? With current time (and a threshold). Quite unusual ... I would like to prefer a better solution, but if the API do not provide this service ... I'll do it

Comment: Yes compare with current time with a threshold. Cause if u add a comment for your old photo that had no caption, the comment become caption for the photo, so comparing just `caption` will not be accurate